# Remove composite Unicode characters in C#

Tags: c#, sql, unicode

We're getting errors in our logs regarding queries such as:

```
SELECT display_term FROM SYS.DM_FTS_PARSER('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, 文看得刺眼（主要是事件表内的显示）将它截图反馈给我们)', 1033, 0, 0) AS DM_FTS_PARSER_1
```

We've found it's the special Unicode characters:

```
（
```

And

```
）
```

Note, these are not normal round brackets, they appear to be a space and a bracket in one char and are some sort of composite Unicode character.

What is the best way to filter out composite Unicode characters, or break them into their composite parts?

Comment: Do you need to [declare your string as unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-parser-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-unicode-for-parsing-special-characters)? *I've never used the parser, and I've not used MSSQL in years, so I'm not sure if this is helpful.

Comment: @Llama changing to `('FORMSOF...` to `(N'FORMSOF...` fixed it, thanks!  Feel free to leave as answer.

Comment: Done :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-parser-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-unicode-for-parsing-special-characters), it seems like you ought to pass the query string as unicode if the database's default collation isn't unicode:

> When you parse a query string, sys.dm_fts_parser uses the collation of the database to which you are connected, unless you specify the query string as Unicode. Therefore, for a non-Unicode string that contains special characters, such as `ü` or `ç`, the output might be unexpected, depending on the collation of the database. To process a query string independently of the database collation, prefix the string with `N`, that is, `N'query_string'`.

I therefore suggest changing your query to this:

```
SELECT display_term FROM SYS.DM_FTS_PARSER(N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, 文看得刺眼（主要是事件表内的显示）将它截图反馈给我们)', 1033, 0, 0) AS DM_FTS_PARSER_1
```